# Extending Request Interface Globally In Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Pretty out of ideas now so I would appreciate some help! I was trying to follow this article on how to extend expresses Request interface. I added an index.d.ts file next to my tsconfig.json which looks like this

```
import { Request } from "express-serve-static-core";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  interface Request {
    user?: any;
  }
}
```

Then, inside my tsconfig, I modified it to add this setting

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./index.d.ts"
    ]
```

Finally, inside an different file, I wrote this function

```
import { NextFunction, Response, Request } from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const validateAuthentication = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authorizationHeader) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authorized" });
  }

  const token = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, (err, user) => {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(403).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

**No error appears in my IDE, but inside my terminal I get the error**

```
src/middleware/validation/validateAuthentication.ts:20:9 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

20     req.user = user;
```

The only work around I have come up with is to write (req as any).user, but I don't want to do this for obvious reasons. Does anyone know how to fix this? My start script is

```
"nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/index.ts"
```

I can  move the

```
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  interface Request {
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Into my index.ts (root of my express app) and it works fine then. Why isn't the method described above working?